# Try an expression multiple times until it succeeds in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have R code that sometimes returns an `NA`, which causes errors downstream.  However, the only reason that it fails stems from a bad random number. Run the expression again with a different starting point, and it produces results that are not `NA`.

I've setup a `while` loop to try the expression multiple times before giving up. Here's an example:

```
attempts <- 0
x <- NA
while(is.na(x) & attempts < 100) {
     attempts <- attempts + 1
     rand <- runif(1)
     x <- ifelse(rand > 0.3, rand, NA)
}
if(attempts == 100) stop("My R code failed")
x
```

I don't like how clunky this is.

Is there a function, package, or method that can help simplify this try-repeat-try-again expression?

Comment: Is there a reason to not set a seed that doesn't cause errors, or deal with the errors downstream more gracefully?

Comment: Don't use `ifelse` when you really want `if(){.}else{}`

Comment: So, you are drawing a random number, but you want the random number to be greater than a value, say 0.3. What would speak against using `rand <- runif(1) + 0.3`? Or, alternatively, `runif(n, min = 0.3 , max = 1)`?

Comment: The example is the principal of it.  My much longer code relies on a package that, based on the random seed it decides to use, sometimes fails, most of the time works.  This will be programmatic, so I can't simply set a seed, I won't know ahead of time what seed will work and what will fail.

Comment: Basically, I'm just looking for a different way to try expression multiple times until the return of that expression satisfies a condition (not NA, not null, not error, something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** We could turn it into a function which returns `x` if it finds one or stops if not.  Also we use `for` instead of `while` and `if` instead of `ifelse`.

```
retry <- function() {
  for(i in 1:100) {
    rand <- runif(1)
    x <- if (rand > 0.3) rand else NA
    if (!is.na(x)) return(x)
  }
  stop("x is NA")
}

retry()
```

**2)** or if you don't want the stop in the function then remove the `stop` line replacing it with a line that returns x and then use this (although it does involve testing x for NA twice):

```
x <- retry()
if (is.na(x)) stop("x is NA")
```

**3)** or another option is to pass the bad value to the function.  Because of lazy evaluation the `bad` argument is only evaluated if it is, in fact, bad:

```
retry2 <- function(bad) {
  for(i in 1:100) {
    rand <- runif(1)
    x <- if (rand > 0.3) rand else NA
    if (!is.na(x)) return(x)
  }
  bad
}

retry2(stop("x is NA"))
```

**4)** If you don't mind testing x for NA twice using `break` also works even without a function:

```
for(i in 1:100) {
  rand <- runif(1)
  x <- if (rand > 0.3) rand else NA
  if (!is.na(x)) break
}
if (is.na(x)) stop("x is NA")
x
```

Comment: A variety of great approaches here, I really like #3.  It's too bad there aren't any packages with this functionality.